# Why can't I cast generic-type with null?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, null, nullable

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133205/why-cannot-convert-null-to-type-parameter-t-in-c), but without casting the T parameter.

**This does not work**

```
public T GetValueG<T>(string Query)
{
    object value = DBNull.Value;    // Read from Database which can return DBNull
    if (value is DBNull)
        return (T)null;
    else
        return (T)value;
}
```

> Error    CS0037    Cannot convert null to 'T' because it is a non-nullable value type

**But this works**

```
public T GetValueG<T>(string Query)
{
    object value = DBNull.Value;    // Read from Database which can return DBNull
    if (value is DBNull)
        value = null;

    return (T)value;
}
```

I know that using constraint type `where T: struct` will make T to be able to be cast with null directly.

But in the second approach, why does it accept an object which is 100% can be null? Why can't I return null directly without an object or something either?

Comment: Why would you do `(T)null` in the first place?  return `default(T)` or just null.

Comment: default(T) for integers and decimals returns zero. I don't need that.. also geenric-type can't return null if it's not nullable generic type. and i want accept null for any Database reader. not default of value.

Comment: I agree, returning `default(T)` is probably best in this case, without knowing more details as to why it needs to specifically be `null`.

Comment: Matt U and Adriani6, Guys i don't want default of type. i always return null for DBNulls. thats all ! :)

Comment: @deveton But you can't assign null to an integer.. unless it's a nullable integer.. `GetValueG<int?>()` then do `default(T)` as your return. In fact, putting the generic type as `int?` `bool?` etc will be sufficient to just return `null` without casting - but that will obviously leave a possible exception.

Comment: Will this work: `return (T)((object)null);`

Comment: @CodingYoshi No, it will not. Again, integers are not nullable. That will throw a NullRef Exception.

Comment: @adriani6 Almost correct. For `T?` it wil work.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Well, yes... same result as `default(T)` with `T?` though, not sure why a dual cast is beneficial either way.

Comment: Re *"something either"*: Do you mean *"something else"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is wrong. Integers are non-nullable types, meaning you can't return null as a value of int or any other not nullable type (as the name suggests...)

Take for example:

`int myInt = null;` - your IDE will right away flag it up with integer being a non-nullable type.

What you want to do is use a nullable type of the actual type you're trying to use e.g. `int?` or `bool?`.

You should be returning `null` or `default(T)` rather than `(T)null` that doesn't make sense, as you can't cast null to e.g. a class type, it'll throw `Object Reference Not Set To An Instance...`.

I would change your function to the following:

```
public T GetValueG<T>(string Query)
{

    object value = DBNull.Value;    // Read from Database which can return DBNull
    if (value is DBNull)
        return default(T);  // `return default;` also valid since C# 7.1 

    return (T)value;
}
```

If a value can be null in your database, then your model should be implementing a nullable of that type to avoid casting exceptions later down the line.

Your function should be called as such `GetValueG<int?>("<query>");`.

Default values for non-nullables can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table).

In your code, rather than checking for null values using `myInt == null` you'd do `myNullableInt.HasValue`.

**Summary**

> The default keyword. will return null for nullable types by default.
>   and default values for other non-nullable types. as OP needs.

`default(bool?)` -> null

`default(bool)` -> false

Comment: oh, I never thought default(bool?) will return null. so yes your approach is a good one. using default is a must with nullable and non-nullable types. I will modify something to make it more concise.