# How to know if the type is "string?" or "string"?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

I need to do a checker to ensure that all parameters have been well implemented. But I am not able to differentiate if a string variable was used unnecessarily nullable (?) or not. For all other types I can differentiate.

```
Condition: Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(ParameterType) != null
```

**Result:**

> string = **false**; string? = **false**;

```
Condition: !p.ParameterType.IsValueType
```

**Result:**

> string = **false**; string? = **false**;

```
Condition: p.ParameterType.IsGenericType
```

**Result:**

> string = **false**; string? = **false**;

Does anyone kindly have any suggestions on how I can differentiate? Thanks

Comment: It is the same at runtime, so you can’t tell the difference with reflection. string? isn’t the same "nullable" as int? .

Answer (score 4):

`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` is used for [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) which are represented via [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-7.0) struct. [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) perform some kind of type-erasure and are not represented as types at runtime. You can try using [`NullabilityInfoContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.nullabilityinfocontext?view=net-7.0) to get this information:

```cs
NullabilityInfoContext context = new();
var nullabilityInfo = context.Create(methodInfo.GetParameters().First());
Console.WriteLine(nullabilityInfo.ReadState);    // Nullable
Console.WriteLine(nullabilityInfo.WriteState);   // Nullable

public interface IMyInterface
{
    Task GetMyModel(MyModel? p);
}

public class MyModel
{
}
```

Comment: well that’s news to me, thought for sure that the information is lost at runtime

Comment: @RandRandom Actually compiler emits attributes that preserve nullability info ([@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAULIGYAEBLAdgFwKYCcBmAhgMZZICSAsgJ5ma6EmwDesSbqmSA4lhtRQHsAJlgA2ACn7CxAfiQAHAJQBuWAF9Y8ZOCRSRo5uqA=)). `NullabilityInfoContext` seems to be [analyzing those](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/NullabilityInfoContext.cs,31).