# null assignment to T? where T : INumber<T>

Tags: c#, generics, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

I want to create a Blazor(wasm) `InputNumber<T>` component `where T : INumber<T>`.

Inside this component I have a simple function to set the Value:

**this compiles good**

```cs
void SetValue(T? value)
{
    if (value is null)
    {
       ....
    }
    ....
}
```

but when I try to call `SetValue(null)` the compiler says:

> CS1503: "cannot convert from `<null>` to `T?`"

I was expecting that if the method parameter is `T?` then I should be able to pass `null` to it.
e.g.

```cs
void SetDecimal(decimal? value)
{
    if (value is null)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

This of course works: `SetDecimal(null);`

What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why T? is not a nullable type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353518/why-t-is-not-a-nullable-type)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here arises from the difference between how [nullable value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) and [nullable reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) types work - former are actually represented as separate type `Nullable<T>` while latter are not and represented by the runtime as metadata. Which results in a bit non-intuitive generic handling of `T?` depended on the constraints (see more [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72911969/2501279)).

One of the possible workarounds is to limit `T` to `struct` (if it is usable for you):

```cs
void SetValue<T>(T? value) where T: struct
{
    if (value is null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading your suggestion i added it to the Component generic constraints, but i took a different approach on settings the Value by checking if the type is Nullable:
bool isNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null;
so if it is, i just set it to default (which will be null in case its nullable) and if it isn't i need to make some calculation to Set the right value.  Thanks!

Comment: @RanKarat was glad to help! If answer works for you - feel free to mark it as accepted one. Or post yours and mark it.

Comment: well it helped me to take other aproch but what i really wanted to reach was:

using System.Numerics;
namespace ConsoleApp3;
public class Number<T> where T : struct, INumber<T>{ }

MyNumber<int?> myNumber = new();

above line make a compile time error: "The type int? must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter T in the generic type or method MyNumber<T>"

i want to be able to use nullable types with INumber<T>.

Comment: @RanKarat yep, that is not possible at the moment as far as I understand. Until C# team will implement lifting for `INumber<T>`.